# Excel VBA Rows to repeat at top EXCEPT for the last page

Tags: excel, vba, printing, excel-2010

I have a dynamic table with 3 rows as the header and then some general remarks underneath the table. I want the header rows to repeat on each page on which the table appears but if the last page only contains the general remarks, then do not repeat the header rows on the last page.

I've set a logic to check if the last page only contains the general remarks but on printing to PDF, page 1 is printed twice and page 2 is not printed (if the worksheet contains 2 pages).

Can anyone help advise how this issue can be resolved? Thanks.

I've tried to add "Application.PrintCommunication = True" and "Worksheets("Quotation").Activate" but it seems that they are of no help.

```
Sub print_with_repeated_rows()

Call Precheck

Dim active_sheet As Variant, page_nums As Variant

Set active_sheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
page_nums = active_sheet.PageSetup.Pages.count

If Last_page_need_title_row Then
    active_sheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=page_nums
Else

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    Err.Clear

    Worksheets("Quotation").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "Print_Titles"
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=page_nums - 1
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=page_nums, To:=page_nums
    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code, and the true statement prints all pages as expected, and the false statement prints all but the last page, and then prints the last page separately, just like the code dictates.

Comment: Thanks for trying the code. It seems that the code works if it is printed to a "real" printer but it doesn't work as expected if it is printed to a PDF printer. Not sure why...

Comment: As a side note, my tests were done to PDF, not a real printer.

Comment: Thanks, Christofer.I wonder why the code doesn't work for me... :(